# Sequence column based on another field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on some legacy code/database, and need to add a field to the database which will record a sequence number related to that column.

LIKE Example table data (current):

```
ID     Q.No.    Session    File No
1      1010       6          1
2      556        6          2
3      598        7          1
4      789        7          2
5      756        8          1
```

Comment: How to ask a question on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: your problem is not clear...

Comment: An example of what you have currently and what you would like to have (with very detailed descriptions) would help alot

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to add a column to a table that already exists. If this is correct, then you must use the ALTER TABLE command.

ALTER TABLE table
ADD COLUMN column_name column_definition;

In your case, let us assume that your table is named `table1` and your sequence numbers are basic integers that are small in size. One might use the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD COLUMN sequence INT;
```

Once you create your column, you can use an UPDATE query to add sequence numbers if the value is based in a simple function of other values, or you can use a series of UPDATES to handle records individually.

Because I am not an SQL expert, I tend to keep my SQL simple, and I do most of my processing in PHP.  I would write a PHP script to assign sequence numbers to each table row, and then send an UPDATE query handling just that row and repeat until the table is filled.